# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown while loading bulk data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

[image]    [image]

When I loaded  100,000 rows with 20 columns intp kendo grid, I am getting 500 error.

So i have checked the response of json , getting memory out of exception . This is the following code.

```
    In the webconfig,have set   

   <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
          <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000"/>
          </webServices>
        </scripting>
      </system.web.extensions>




    This is the mvc controller.



  public JsonResult JqueryKendoGridVirtualScrolling()
                {

                    using (var s = new KendoEntities())
                    {
                        var x = s.premiumsbytreaties.ToList().Take(100000);

                        if (x != null)
                        {
                            var jsonResult = Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
                            return jsonResult;
                            //return Json(x.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }

                        else
                        {

                            return null;
                        }
                    };


                }

It is working fine for 6 columns.But not working for 15 columns.
```

working fine with 20,000 thousand  record,see the output

[image]

Comment: 100000 rows with 15 columns - what do you expect. (and how could a user possibly absorb that much info. Use a paging mechanism

Comment: Looking at the stack trace I suspect something internal to the JSON serialisation that Kendo uses is blowing past the 2GB object size limit of .NET. With a download of that size your site will be unusable even over a LAN.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke my requirement is like that they don't need pagination ,so i have used the below technique of kendo grid http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data, But mvc response itself i am getting an error.

Comment: implement lazy loading, load on demand from server, refer demo .telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data.

Comment: Sometimes you have to tell customers/managers that their requirement is infeasible.

Comment: @AnilKumar , right now my requirement is like taht ,they don't want pagination to the grid,so i have used  virtualization-of-remote-data- concept.i am getting error in mvc json response

Comment: load on demand from server, refer demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data

Comment: @Anilkumar. i have done through server side pagination of kendo,but they don't need pagination,In this situation what i have to do

Comment: @richard,how much mvc json response will support,because i have set the  configuraton above JsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000" for getting an error after loading 5000 record , so have used that ,now again getting error in mvc

Comment: have you even look for demo given by me, before commenting. Lazy loading/on demand loading is not paging always, this is also possible on scroll.

Comment: in case you are fond of sending all data to browser and then bind to it there, then you may change serialization technique, like http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Half a gigabyte is vastly too much data for a response (unless you are downloading a file). Remember the browser is going to have to parse and process that data as well once received.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

1. 500,000,000 characters is too long for the JSON content of an HTTP Response. This will take time to pass over the network and that is before the client browser can parse and process the data (taking time and memory).

   1% of this is still too much.
2. You are *not* using Kendo's support for "[Grid / Virtualization of remote data](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/virtualization-remote-data)".

   In their example the action's first parameter is `[DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request` and then this is used (with the `ToDataSource` extension method) in creating the response.

   Like with AJAX methods supporting Kendo Grids (and other controls) 
   these work together to pass paging, sorting and filtering parameters and
   apply to the data before it is returned.

   If your data is an `IQueryable<T>` for a suitable db provider this will
   happen on the database.